# Azure Function multiple JWT issuers

Tags: azure, jwt, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, auth0

I have an Azure Function v4 which is using JwtBinding attribute

```
[JwtBinding("%JwtBinding:Issuer%", "%JwtBinding:Audience%")] AuthorizedModel auth
```

from `HexMaster.Functions.JwtBinding` package.

All good so far because initially, I've used only Auth0 as an auth provider. But recently I switched to Azure AD B2C and some of the users might have an old token (emitted by Auth0) and some of them will have the new one (emitted by Azure).

Is there any way to update the Jwt token validation to support multiple Issuers and Audiences?

From their documentation (package Github repo) it seems to not have support for this. Or is there any other way to do it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in Authentication feature of Azure Functions?

Comment: Yes, but this will take a while and for the moment I need a quick solution.

Comment: If you just need validation a JWT token and have the /.well-known/openid-configuration , I think you can set it up in 5 minutes

Comment: One way is to use the JwtValidationOptions class.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization.InProcess](https://nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization.InProcess) or [DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization.Isolated](https://nuget.org/packages/DarkLoop.Azure.Functions.Authorization.Isolated) depending on which model you are using. Read more [here](https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functions-policy-based-auth-for-functions-v4-in-proc-and-isolated).